# How does the linux kernel detect which hardware is present/driver to load?

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware

I'm having trouble finding resources on how the linux kernel actually finds the hardware, that it is running on.

For example, what kind of graphics card there is, so it knows which driver to load. Or if there is a graphics card present at all.

I picked up somewhere, that it could have something to do with ACPI tables, but I'm at a loss what to search for.

Comment: There was such a great answer here. Really sad it was deleted.